# SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection error in AXIS java application

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, axis

I have java app that uses Axis to get data from web service. web service is accessed via HTTPS. It works fine on my local PC, but customer uses proxy. I added setting for proxy:

```
System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
System.getProperties().put( "proxyHost", host);
System.getProperties().put( "proxyPort", port);
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,
            password.toCharArray());
    }
});
```

but customers get exception:

```
faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

Can anybody help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was unable to solve this problem. Our app was rewritten using plain HTTP POST requests (with Apache HTTPClient 3.0), i.e. without Axis.

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
```

That does nothing. Remove. There is no such property in the JDK.

```
 System.getProperties().put( "proxyHost", host);
 System.getProperties().put( "proxyPort", port);
```

If you are using SSL these should be https.proxyHost/https.proxyPort respectively. For plaintext connections, http.proxyHost/http.proxyPort.

Comment: Actually we tried to use  https.proxyHost/https.proxyPort as well, the same error. BTW, we use java 1.4